# httplib2 download progress bar in python

Tags: python, progress-bar, httplib2

Is it possible to display the percentage a file has downloaded in python while using httplib2? I know you can with urllib2 but I want to use httplib2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `httplib2` doesn't have any kind of progress beacon callback, so it simply blocks until the request is finished.

Comment: There is a bug report for it here http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/issues/detail?id=5

Answer (score 0):

i'm not very sure with how to use async()
seems it's already OFFICIALLY solved.

and it's possible to modify httplib2 by your self:
(add a callback function arg to the request() func)
**in class Http:
in def _request:** modify it to:

```
def _request(self, conn, host, absolute_uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey,callback=None):
```

**in def _conn_requst:** modify it to:

```
def _conn_request(self, conn, request_uri, method, body, headers,callback=None):
```

modify this below

```
if method == "HEAD":
    conn.close()
else:
    if not callback:
        content = response.read()
    else:
        while 1:
           content=response.read(callback[0])
           if not content:break
           callback[1]()
```

when use you can type like this:

```
resp, content = h.request("http://stackoverflow.com", [8192,callbackfunc])
```

the first 8192 is chunk size, and callbackfunc is the callback function you defined(like in urllib)